# Moving value of the same variable into a new vector based on all possible combinations?

Tags: r, dataframe

Starting from the A object

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

I want to obtain the following matrix with B and C:

```
     B C
[1,] 1 2
[2,] 1 3
[3,] 1 4
[4,] 2 3
[5,] 2 4
[6,] 3 4
```

Any idea on how to code this? I was trying to use mutate function in dplyr but I have not managed it.

How to implement this in a dplyr pipe?

Comment: Try with `combn` i.e. `t(combn(A, 2))`

Comment: Thanks. But how to implement it in a dplyr pipe of a dataframe?

Comment: If you need a pipe `A %>% {combn(., 2)} %>% t`